# Does Jorte synch with Google Calendar?

Tags: sync, calendar

When I create events on Google Calendar, they don't end up in Jorte. Does Jorte truly sync events with Google Calendar or does it just import events when you set it up and then forget about it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I use Jorte to add events to my Google Calendar linked accout without problems and without any specific setting tuning.

Comment: I take that to mean that the "synch" only works in one direction.